# Jquery Wrap multiple tags in a div inside each

Tags: jquery, html, css

Each:

```
$.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (index, item) {

                          $('.feed')
                             .append( '<h1><a href='+item.link+'>'+ item.title+'</a></h1>')
                             .append('<span>'+item.publishedDate+'</span></br>')
                             .append('<span>'+item.contentSnippet + '</span>');


                        });
```

Results from Jquery Each Loop:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<span>Description</span><br/>
<span>Date</span>
```

I am expecting:

```
<div class="news">
<h1>Title</h1>
<span>Description</span><br/>
<span>Date</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `('.news').html('<h1>Title</h1><span>Description</span><br/><span>Date</span>')`

Comment: $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (index, item) {
              //console.log(data);
                 
                 $('.feed')
                 //console.log(item)
                    //.append( '<div>')
                    .append( '<h1><a href='+item.link+'>'+ item.title+'</a></h1>')
                    .append('<span>'+item.publishedDate+'</span></br>')
                    .append('<span>'+item.contentSnippet + '</span>');


               });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "results of jQuery each loop" in this context. $.each loops over a set of elements (or a regular array potentially) given the selector you use. Without more context, I can only tell you how to wrap an element in two ways.

The first way is wrapping elements on a page already, so for instance, if what you had above is a set of elements from a selector match (or otherwise), you could wrap them like using [$.wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

```
$(yourelements).wrapAll('<div class="news">');
```

If you have the above HTML as a string, then it's easy enough to wrap that block of elements:

```
var html = "<h1>Title</h1>"
           + "<span>Description</span><br/>"
           + "<span>Date</span>",
    news = $('<div class="news">').innerHTML(html);
```

Again, I'd need more context around the each loop you're referring to in order to offer a better solution.